# Qt and script system

Tags: c++, qt

there are a nice binding of script system for Qt, which uses javascript. With metaobjects built in qt it gives a big power for a programmer.

I'm rewriting game from another libraries with using Qt. Now I want to replace python script system with something faster. I dunno whether built-in Qt scripts are quite fast for my purposes? Or QLua would be better choise for my case?

Any numbers/statistic is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What language are the other libraries written in?

Comment: @cbamber85 they are written with c++

Comment: Why do you want scripting support?  If you're writing a game surely performance is critical, so why not stick to C++ - the libraries native language.

Comment: @cbamber85 In game development there is a plenty places where object logic code are more like configuration.

I have bad times migrating from python to JS, and mostly it was easier to put that code to C++. Also QML is very usefull  and it is built over JS. However having more than one scripting languge is very confusing and that's why we decided to put python away.

Answer (score 1):

This article on [QtScript in 4.6](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/11/23/qtscript-in-46/) discusses the improvements in performance in QtScript in 4.6 over 4.5, it states:

> Qt 4.6′s QtScript implementation is based on WebKit’s JavaScript engine, JavaScriptCore (you might’ve also heard it being referred to as “SquirrelFish” or “SquirrelFish Extreme”).

Another article discusses the [technologies in SquirrelFish Extreme](http://www.webkit.org/blog/214/introducing-squirrelfish-extreme/), which include:

- Bytecode Optimizations
- Polymorphic Inline Cache
- Context Threaded JIT
- Regular Expression JIT

If you need full native code performance, but want to allow the system to be extended, you may want to look into [How to Create Qt Plugins](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/plugins-howto.html), you could even use the Qt plugin system to write plugins that run JavaScript, Lua or Python to extend the system.